# Как в документе 1С изменить сортировку?

Tags: 1с

столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Использую 1с комплексная автоматизация. Есть документ "Инвентаризационная опись". У этого документа есть форма печати "ИНВ-3". Возникла необходимость поменять сортировку номенклатуры[image: инвентаризационная опись], чтобы она была отсортирована по артикулу номенклатуры. С 1С еле знаком, не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста необходимый код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Я бы рад скинуть код, если бы знал в какой его части нужно внести изменения.

Answer (score 0):

1. Зайти в Справочник Дополнительные отчеты и обработки, и найти там поиском ИНВ-3 или Инвентаризационная опись
2. Если в п 1 нашли, значит печатная форма в виде доп-обработки, нужно выгрузить ее в файл, этот файл открыть в конфигураторе и далее исправить Запрос получения данных добавлением "УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО ИнвНомер"
3. Если в п1 не нашли, в конфигураторе открыть базу, глобальным поиском найти "ИНВ-3", и далее также исправить запрос добавлением "УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО ИнвНомер"

Либо просто созраняйте в Эксель и сортируйте !